# Is there a solution of sync the share files' share restricted with Azure File Sync?

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-files, sharefile

I am using Azure File Sync to sync two servers' folders. Where do I need to sync the folders' share services?

I tried to sync the shared folder with some access restricted, I found the Azure File Sync can sync the access restricted but can't sync the folders' share services.

I want to find a solution to sync the folders' share services what could ensure the users can use their share files in the second server (for DR) when the primary server is down.

Comment: May I know what are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide more details?  Eg:  when I copy files or folders to Cloud File storage the files or folders are not sync to on- premise server ?

Comment: I want to create a DR environment of my on-premise file server at Azure to ensure users can use share folder when the on-premise file server meet some disaster.    So I want to use Azure File Sync to Sync the On-premise server and cloud server, but I find an issue that Azure File Sync doesn't support the share folders'  share access permission.